# How can I view a full description of god's power?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

Today I joined Zin for the first time, and I noticed the following:

[image: screenshot of an ellipsis at the end of Recitation description preview in the console]

More precisely, when I hovered over first Zin's power, Recitation, its description appeared in the console. However, the description is clearly cut off too early and there is an ellipsis at the bottom of the console.

I can right click at tiles, monsters, items, skills and spells in order to get a full description. But when I right click at Recite's button (or a button of any other godly power), nothing happens. Furthermore, there is no mention of how to get the full description in Recite's tooltip either.

So - how can I view a full description of god's power?

(I'm playing desktop tiles, version 0.20.1.)

Comment: Good news! It's a bug that apparently was fixed [in a recent commit](https://github.com/crawl/crawl/commit/5a59f1690dff240ab33a916b246ea1da1e3e6a4d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `Alt-A` to open your abilities menu, press `!` to switch to descriptions, then press the letter for the ability or click on the ability of the description you wish to read.

I think there should be a way to open the abilities menu via the GUI instead of a keypress, but I'm not sure what it is if there is one.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to make a feature request for that on mantis.